# chrome recaptcha allowall in iframe on subdomain

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, recaptcha, x-frame-options

I'm using google's reCaptcha, which works fine in a subdomain, but when I try to use an iframe to present that subdomain's page in the main site, api.js and webworker.js end up using SAMEORIGIN and causing chrome to not show the file.  The subdomain is presenting as ALLOWALL on the x-frame-options, but those two return SAMEORIGIN, causing chrome to get annoyed and drop it back to Deny.

I'm able to copy the api.js file into the subdomain site, which results in the x-frame-options for that file to be ALLOWALL, but the reCaptcha code ends up loading webworker.js, which loads from google, and I can't change that.  I'm not even sure where it's loading that, as it's not in the api.js file.

Any suggestions aside from moving the subdomain code entirely into the main site?  I'm not going to be able to move the recaptcha into the main site as it would then run outside the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and other browsers don't really support anything but DENY and SAMEORIGIN. The solution is to set Content-Security-Policy with the frame-ancestors directive set to all the (sub)domains that should be allowed to frame. This would typically be either "'self' subdomain.example.com" or simply "*.example.com". IE won't understand it and consequently ignore it, the other browsers that understand it will now ignore X-Frame-Options.